# Cross-referecing columns in Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, finance, amortization

I'm trying to build an amortization schedule using Snowflake-SQL however I need two columns to reference each other in order to calculate the active and the present value. In excel, it would be something like this:

[image: present value]
[image: active value]

In SQL, I tried doing it like this but it doesn't work:

```
,LAG(present_value) OVER (PARTITION BY ti.request_id ORDER BY ti.reference_date) AS active_value
,active_value - c.installment_amount AS present_value
```

How am I able to replicate what I did using excel in SQL?

Comment: Hi - as your screenshots don’t include the column and row headers, showing the formula doesn’t really help e.g. we’ve got no idea which cell is $C$9, for example

Comment: one method would be a recursive CTE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71799967/how-to-recursively-calculate-rows-based-on-previous-rows-in-snowflake/71803309#71803309
OR you could use a UDTF

Comment: for others "playing at home" the interest `$C$4` is around `26.3669472168149%` (annualized) and `0.0007223821155291760` on a daily basis  and the period payment `$C$9` is around `304.90`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so with a janky CTE for the seed data:

```
with data(y,start_date, amount, interest_y_c4, payment_c9, interest_d_c4_p1) as (
    select *
       ,(0.0007223821155291760::double) + 1.00::double
    from values
    (1,'2021-11-10', 1690.96::double, 0.263669472168149::double, 304.90::double)
), payment_days(x,days, acc_days) as (
    select *
        ,sum(column2) over(order by column1)
    from values
    (1, 0),
    (2, 28),
    (3, 35),
    (4, 28),
    (5, 24),
    (6, 31),
    (7, 30)
), rc as (
```

and a recursive CTE this can be solved:

```
with RECURSIVE rec_cte as (
    select
        d.y,
        pd.x + 1 as x,
        pd.days,
        dateadd('days',pd.acc_days, d.start_date)::date as payment_date,
        d.amount as active_value,
        0.0::double as interest,
        d.amount as present_value
    from data as d
    join payment_days as pd
        on pd.x = 1

    UNION ALL

    select 
        d.y,
        pd.x + 1 as x,
        pd.days,
        dateadd('days',pd.acc_days, d.start_date)::date as payment_date,
        round(r.present_value * pow(d.interest_d_c4_p1, pd.days),10) as _active_value,
        (_active_value - r.present_value) as interest,
        greatest(0, _active_value - d.payment_c9) as present_value

    from rec_cte as r
    join data as d
        on r.y = d.y
    join payment_days as pd
        on r.x = pd.x
)
select y as customer_id
    ,days
    ,payment_date
    ,floor(active_value,2) as active_value
    ,floor(interest,2) as interest
    ,floor(present_value,2) as present_value
from rec_cte
```

giving:

| CUSTOMER_ID | DAYS | PAYMENT_DATE | ACTIVE_VALUE | INTEREST | PRESENT_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2021-11-10 | 1,690.96 | 0 | 1,690.96 |
| 1 | 28 | 2021-12-08 | 1,725.49 | 34.53 | 1,420.59 |
| 1 | 35 | 2022-01-12 | 1,456.96 | 36.36 | 1,152.06 |
| 1 | 28 | 2022-02-09 | 1,175.59 | 23.53 | 870.69 |
| 1 | 24 | 2022-03-05 | 885.91 | 15.22 | 581.01 |
| 1 | 31 | 2022-04-05 | 594.16 | 13.15 | 289.26 |
| 1 | 30 | 2022-05-05 | 295.6 | 6.33 | 0 |

I was not 100% of you daily interest rate or payment, so solving those took that most time. So next please just include them.

I also would not use `double` money.. but my first take at use number(20,10) was not so successful..

Comment: Thanks!! Sorry for the poorly done explanation, your solution really helped a lot!